# Projects disappears from PyDeb Package Explorer... what am i doing wrong>

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I am trying to get to grips with PyDev, Git and egit. But when I import a project to my PyDev is disappears straight away.

I followed the excellent video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RRPQpDoaAk) about how to connect egit (eclipse) to my GitHub account and I was able to download the test project I made in work

I then attempt to add the project to my PyDev Package explorer so I can work on it at home. I thought it should be fairly simple but i ended up using this tutorial ([Eclipse / PyDev features: Import existing project)](https://sites.google.com/site/bcgeopython/examples/eclipse-pydev/eclipse-pydev-features-import-existing-project)

The steps are ....

> 1. right click in the Pydev Package Explorer Window
> 2. File->Import
> 3. Navigate to the root directory for the project that you want to
>      import.  (The root directory is the directory in which you will
>      find the .project and the pydevproject files.
> 4. Usually you will only find one project in a directory.  Select the
>      project that you want to import
> 5. Now press finish and eclipse will import the project into your eclipse
>      session.

However when I do this the imported project appears for a brief second in the PyDev Package Explorer then disappears

It does however stay in the resource tab of Eclipse. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The PyDev package explorer doesnt seem to be that different from the ordinary package explorer, so my guess its an issue with the working sets.

In the view menu of the pydev package explorer, what are your `Top elements`? If its `Working sets`, go to `Select working sets...` to verify that you have selected all working sets, and that all projects are in a working set.